# Stackexchange site blocks me for "Too Many Requests" when associating all my accounts

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I initially joined [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), my account associations got borked and didn't get the +100 rep that I got on all the other SE sites I joined.  So, I finally figured out that if I went to associations and clicked the bottom button to clear them all, I could reassociate, get my +100 and pass go.

Well, that worked for about 4 associations and then on the next one I got:

> We're sorry...
>
> There are an unusual number of
>   requests coming from this IP address.
>
> To protect our users, we can't process
>   any more requests from this IP address
>   right now.
>
> We'll restore access as quickly as
>   possible, so try again soon.
>
> If you believe you have reached this
>   page in error, contact us.

It lasted only a couple minutes and I was back in business.  I associated 4 more accounts and the pattern repeats.

I take it this is a bug and someone should know.  Perhaps an easy solution could be to have an Associate All button.

Comment: This happened to me, too. It's a test to see whether you really care enough. (I passed.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accounts tab no longer renders one .png flair per site you have accounts on (leading to say, 45 individual HTTP requests on that page if you had an account on [*every* site in our network](https://stackexchange.com/sites)), so this should no longer be a problem.